# How to set default date in ion-datetime in Ionic 2

Tags: javascript, typescript, datetime, ionic-framework, ionic2

On my `page.html` form, I have `ion-datetime` field, on clicking it, Ionic calendar is opened to select the required date. I want it to show current date when my form is opened. I am trying with the below code but it is still showing `blank` field.

`page.html` code:

```
  <ion-datetime displayFormat="DD/MM/YYYY" name="myDate" [(ngModel)]="myDate"></ion-datetime>
```

`page.ts` code:

```
 public myDate=new Date();
```

How can I show current date on my HTML page?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to provide date in the form of [ISO 8601 Datetime Format: YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mmZ](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/datetime/DateTime/#iso-8601-datetime-format-yyyy-mm-ddthh-mmz) as per the documentation.

Set your initial date as:

```
public myDate:string=new Date().toISOString();
```